# american option confusion

Tags: binomial, american, discrete-dividends

I've coded up a binomial tree version of the "Known Dollar Dividend" part of section 21.3 of Hull 10th Edition.  I reproduce the answer in the book's example and also reproduce correctly a few spot-checked option prices in Bloomberg for which there's an upcoming dividend.  I think I have a mistake, however, because I get the following result which seems wrong to me:  Consider a 3 month american call on a dividend-free stock where curr px = strike = 50, vol = 30%, rate = 0.  This is worth ~2.98.  I believe that's the right price.  Now consider a 6 month american call where as before we take curr px = strike = 50, vol = 30% and rate =0 but the underlying stock pays a 40 dollar dividend in 3 months.  I find that option to be worth around 0.60 which makes no sense to me:  My logic is that it's basically a 3 month option because it's almost certain that the $40 dollar ex-div price drop will make the final 3 months of optionality worthless so I'd say it should be worth the same 2.98, perhaps plus a tiny bit.  In any case it should be worth strictly no less than the 3 month option with the same terms.  Isn't that right?  Assuming someone agrees with my logic, do you have any gotchas to direct me toward vis a vis the coding logic?  Thanks in advance for any help, and apologies for the long-ish question.

Comment: I think the answer may be simply that the lognormal vol is generating less absolute price movement on the first 3 months of the 6 month option than in the 3 month option because the U,D movements (pure fns of the the lognormal vol) are being applied to the spot price - pv(dividend)  rather than to the spot price.  More simply, the model is different with or w/o the dividend so the vol should be also...

Comment: yep, the problem comes down to rescaling the vol.  w/o dividends the initial moves are of size S * sigma * sqrt(dt).  when there's a dividend in the future (before expiry) with present value D then the models' initial moves are of size (S-D) * sigma' * sqrt(dt).  thus to approximate the same stock diffusion I need to choose sigma' = sigma * S / (S-D).  when i do that the 6 month option price with the 3 month giant dividend has the same price as the 3 month no-div option.  problem solved.  hope it's useful for someone :D